# Как лучше всего сверстать такие линии?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как лучше всего создать такие линии чтобы расстояние было равномерное. Before задать каждому?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: Это потому что я не приложил код?

Answer (score 3):

Можно так

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: "|";
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```